# Online library for image annotation with arrows?

Tags: library, javascript, images

Has anyone come accross a JavaScript/jQuery based library that helps to annotate images with arrows?

Would be great for us to use in our project.

[image: image annotated with arrows]

Comment: What do you mean with "Online"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried djaodjin-annotate.js before? It should be exactly what your looking for,

**[djaodjin-annotate.js](https://djaodjin.com/blog/jquery-plugin-to-annotate-images.blog.html)** ([Open Source](https://github.com/djaodjin/djaodjin-annotate/))

djaodjin-annotate.js is a simple jquery plugin allowing you to annotate a screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a commercial product, the [LEADTOOLS](https://www.leadtools.com/) JavaScript libraries can definitely do this for you. There is an online demo that you can test out as well found [here](http://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/DocumentViewer/index.html). Below you will see a screenshot of the demo with arrow annonations as well as other annotations that can be added:

[image]

If you are interested, you can evaluate the toolkit and make any modifactions you please. The [free eval](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main) last for 60 days and includes demos as well as the source code.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of this product

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/diagram/defaultfunctionalities) allows you to annnotate images. Simple sample application:[link](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/vun3r1l0).

[image: Essential Diagram with annotation]

The whole suite of controls is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

We just released a developer library/api for annotation product [Markup Hero](https://markuphero.com). It's quite slick and easy to implement. Here is a demo of it in action with Notion (this is just a demo, Notion hasn't integrated it... yet). But we have a handful of SaaS companies integrating. Quite flexible and clean.

**30 Second Video Demo:** https://youtu.be/miB3yD1xlTI

**Quick Interactive Demo:** https://markuphero.com/try/notion-annotation-api-demo.html

**Info on the library is here:** https://markuphero.com/integrations/annotation-api.html

**Documentation for the library is here:** https://docs.markuphero.com/#summary